# Loopback/Echo bytes received over serial port

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, embedded-linux, busybox

On an embedded Linux system running Busybox I am trying to receive bytes over a serial port and echo back everything received.

The system setup is like this:
Linux <-USB-> FTDI chip <-UART-> MCU
On the UART line I have a logic analyser monitoring the data between the FTCI chip and the MCU. Both the MCU and Linux have the same UART configuration.

The script I have written runs on the Linux system and is supposed to send back all data it received from the MCU.

So far I have this simple Bash script which is to receive bursts of data 62 bytes long. The timeout is set to 5 seconds as a sort of alive signal.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Enable debugging
set -x

# Set the baudrate of the port 
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 1500000

while true
do 
  # Read 62 bytes with a timout of 5 seconds to variable RESP.
  read -N62 -t5 RESP < /dev/ttyUSB0

  # Print out how many bytes we received
  echo ${#RESP}

  # Send back the data, -n for no trailing new line
  echo -n $RESP > /dev/ttyUSB0
done
```

There are a few problems I have with this script:

1. Not all bytes are received consistently. I've been testing now for some time an only seen the full number of bytes once.
2. It outputs only 0xFF values on the UART bus, this is observed through the logic analyser.

What am I missing here in order to receiving the correct data and send it back correctly?

Comment: Probably because 1500000 is not a baud rate many devices will support. Try with 9600 or 115200 instead.

Comment: The FTDI chip is specked to 3M baud.

Comment: That doesnt mean it supports every intermediate value.

Comment: Tested with 115200, unfortunately same problem.

Comment: Your script fails for me with: `line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'`  You are unclear as to what is at the other end of this UART connection (although you mention a "*loopback*" in the title).  What is "*loopback **or** echo*" supposed to mean?  "*Not all bytes are received consistently*" -- That's only a vague summation.  What are the details?   "*It outputs only 0xFF values on the UART bus.*" -- How did you determine this? FYI a UART is not a "*bus*", but a serial link.  Both ends of the link must have matching line configurations, but you set just the baudrate on one end.

Comment: @sawdust Your absolutely right. My explanation did not paint the whole picture. I also corrected the EOF error. When manually copying the script I should have used {} instead of ().

Comment: The corrected script with my modifications for **stty**, removal of the loop, and a longer read timeout performs as expected with Busybox v1.31.1.  The script does echo text that is sent to it.  You still have not provided details of what you perceive as receive problems, nor the data format.  I suspect that you may have a  scheme that unreasonably expects the sender and receiver to be synchronized.  BTW termios can be configured to perform the echo.  But using echo in a machine-to-machine setup is bizarre, and is an inferior method for checking integrity.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for checking! If I understand correctly you removed the loop and are now able to receive one set of data? What is the stty modification you mention? 

Our data format is verified on a windows platform talking to the MCU using a different FTDI chip. On the windows platform we are able to send at least 100 messages per second with between 62 and 230 bytes per message. A message consists of a STX, data length, data, CRC and ETX.

What would be a better method to figure out why the Linux setup is not working while the windows one does? I thought simple script would help.

Comment: So your data is binary rather than text. On Linux you're not accessing a serial port, but rather a serial terminal with the termios layer inserted into the mix.  As previously mentioned, your script only sets the baudrate, and leaves all other line and terminal settings to chance.  For binary data you should (explicitly) configure the serial terminal to noncanonical (aka raw) mode.  But Bash's `read` is for a canonical operation (i.e read a line of text), so I'm not sure that a shell script is appropriate for binary data.

Comment: @sawdust That is helpfull! Will look into setting the port to raw/noncanonical mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the suggestions made by @sawdust I was able to get a working script.
In the end I stopped using the `read` command. I was unable to get it to work in raw mode. I could not use `termios` as this in to available on my Busybox system. I got a working setup using `dd`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 1500000

dd if=/dev/ttyUSB0 count=62 of=/dev/ttyUSB0
```